# Multi slash mapping showing page without css in Spring Boot -Thymeleaf Project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I have a mapping like this in my controller in this the page come completely fine.

```
@GetMapping("/recruiter/recruiter-dashboard")
public String recruiterJitsiMeetingManagementPage(Model model, HttpSession session) {
        
    List<String> userDetails = (List<String>) session.getAttribute("MY_SESSION_MESSAGES");

    if (userDetails == null) {
        userDetails = new ArrayList<>();
        return "redirect:/";
    }else {
            
        int userId = Integer.valueOf(userDetails.get(2));
        String userName = userDetails.get(3);
        String userEmail = userDetails.get(0);
        int roleId = Integer.valueOf(userDetails.get(4));
        String roleType = userDetails.get(5);
            
        model.addAttribute("userDetailsList", userService.getUserDetailsByEmailId(userEmail));
            
        String email_id = userEmail;
        model.addAttribute("loggedInUserEmail", email_id);

        String role = "Interviewer";    
        model.addAttribute("jobsList", jobService.getJobsList());
            model.addAttribute("screenedList", screenProfileService.getScreenedProfileByUser(email_id));
        JitsiMeeting jitsiMeeting = new JitsiMeeting();
        model.addAttribute("jitsiMeeting", jitsiMeeting);
            
        return "jitsi_meeting";
    }
}
```

But, In this when i try the same the whole page comes but without css, Please let me know what is the issue here?

```
@GetMapping("/user/password-reset")
public String forgotPasswordPage() {
        return "forgot_password";
}
```

I have multi checked the pages which these are calling are spelled correctly and the css called are also correct.

I need to get that page correctly when i call `/user/password-reset`

Comment: Are you using Spring Security? Can the CSS be loaded if there is no logged in user? You can check the browser dev tools to if that is the case.